# explain Givens rotation chain for maintaining Cholesky factorization

Tags: python, simplex, linear-algebra

I'm attempting to implement the dual face algorithm from Pan's book chapter 22 (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-19-0147-8).

The part in question is pasted here:
[image: Alg 22.5.1]

Can you please explain what these rotations are supposed to accomplish? I recognize that it's trying to update L after deleting a column from $B$, but I don't understand what is necessary to keep $L$ bound to $B$ in that scenario. Why are there two commas after the $i$? I have $L, k, p$; I need $\hat{L}$. How do I determine $\hat{L}$ using Numpy/Scipy?

Comment: First try reading https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Givens-rotation and https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat610/class0208.pdf .

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ might be more likely to get a suitable answer for this question.